# How to generate xls file content without creating a file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am working on the Django REST server which does some calculations. I store these calculations as JSON and I want to create an endpoint that will generate a .xlsx file based on these JSON results and upload it to AWS S3 just like this:

```py
s3.meta.client.put_object(
    Bucket = credentials['AWS_BUCKET_NAME'],
    Key=file_path,
    Body=file_content,
)
```

But there is the problem - every lib I checked for generating .xlsx content is creating a file, which I don't want to. Any solutions?

I understand that I can generate the file (with "xlsxwriter" for example), pull out the content, and delete it, but this way seems not quite the best:D

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can use an `io.BytesIO` object virtually anywhere you can use a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) said in the comments, i used `io.BytesIO` object with [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) library, because it has 'in_memory' option on Workbook object initialization.

```py
output = BytesIO()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {"in_memory":True})

# After all manipulations with workbook
workbook.close()
output.seek(0)

# Uploading to AWS S3 using "boto3"
s3.meta.client.put_object(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=file_path,
    Body=output,
)
```